# How do I calculate the difference of two row values associated with the same column value in R?

Tags: r, aggregation

I have an R question.

I want to calculate whether there is an increase(1)/decrease(0) in two row values `sjc` associated with the same `Record_ID` in another column?

This is the code to generate the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("Record_ID" = c(1, 1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
                   "sjc"       = c(3,28,1,1,2,0,2,4,9,2))
```

original data frame

[image]

And this is how I want it to look:

Results dataframe

[image]

I appreciate the help!

Comment: take a look at dplyr's `lead()` and `lag()`, or data.table's `shift()`-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, we can use `ave`, group by `Record_ID` and check if the difference of `sjc` values is greater than 0 or not.

```
df$inc_dec <- with(df, ave(sjc, Record_ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x) > 0)))

df
#   Record_ID sjc inc_dec
#1          1   3      NA
#2          1  28       1
#3          2   1      NA
#4          2   1       0
#5          3   2      NA
#6          3   0       0
#7          4   2      NA
#8          4   4       1
#9          5   9      NA
#10         5   2       0
```

With `dplyr`, we can use `lag` to get previous value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Record_ID) %>%  mutate(inc_dec = +(sjc - lag(sjc) > 0))
```

and similarly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, inc_dec := +(sjc - shift(sjc) > 0), Record_ID]
```

Comment: Such a quick reply! I used the dplyr solution and it worked like a charm. Thank you! Could you explain the portion inside the mutate function, please? I'm not sure I understand how it works.

Comment: @SaraAltamirano We are comparing current `sjc` value with the previous `sjc` value using `lag`. The `+` in front converts the logical value of (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) to `1/0` respectively.